# Err HTTP 200 in Node.Js on Windows Server 2012

Tags: javascript, node.js

I created an application that is running correctly, but when run on the server this error is occurring.
Server: Windows Server 2012.
Any suggestion?

```
iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.

HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500
HTTP subStatus: 1002
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error
You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled configuration setting is 'true'.

In addition to the log of stdout and stderr of the node.exe process, consider using debugging and ETW traces to further diagnose the problem.

The node.exe process has not written any information to stderr or iisnode was unable to capture this information. Frequent reason is that the iisnode module is unable to create a log file to capture stdout and stderr output from node.exe. Please check that the identity of the IIS application pool running the node.js application has read and write access permissions to the directory on the server where the node.js application is located. Alternatively you can disable logging by setting system.webServer/iisnode/@loggingEnabled element of web.config to 'false'.
```

Comment: You actually have a 500 error. Something went wrong in the server. Without more information we can’t say what

Comment: There's not enough information to answer your question. What do you mean by 'installing on the server'? Looks like IISNode. Maybe this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56961099/how-to-correct-iisnode-http-500-substatus-1002-process-request-error

Comment: "run on the server"...